# Ajax request times out after 10 minutes, how to increase it

Tags: ajax, apache, jsf, timeout, wildfly

I am using wildfly server, apache httpd proxy and jsf for my application.

```
<h:form id='form' style='display:none' prependId="false">
       <h:commandLink id="link">
            <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.retriveData()}" render="confirm" onevent="onLoad" />
       </h:commandLink>
 </h:form>
```

This is the ajax call that is getting called.

`retriveData` is a timetaking method which will take around 14 minutes to complete the task .

I am getting timeout after 10 minutes from the server side.

[image]

Is there any configuration in wildfly server side to increase the timeout delay to 15 minutes ?

Is it can be a wildfly configuraion or apache httpd configuration ?

Comment: Bad design to do something that takes this long in an a synchronous call. Make it async and use e.g. a push mechanism to notify the client things are finished

Comment: Its an ajax call only .

Comment: Then please take a step back and learn all technologies and what they are used for...

Comment: Any suggestion on increasing the timeout ?

Comment: No, and I'm not going to search for one or give one, since it is bad design.

Comment: Fire the one that made the decison to **not** minimally change things ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Kukeltje comment, you have a design issue with your application.

You wrote:

> retriveData is a timetaking method which will take around 14 minutes to complete the task
>   (...)
>   Is there any configuration in wildfly server side to increase the
>   timeout delay to 15 minutes ?

So what if you increase this timeout delay to 15 minutes and task takes a little bit longer than usual let's say 16 minutes?

Then, according to your GUI screenshot, you have a "Loading..." modal which appears during this treatment. So my understanding is that the user just has to leave and take a coffee when treatment runs for 14 minutes... (Have you taken into account that some users might not like coffee?)

Thus, you should really consider doing this treatment asynchronously, with the help of [@Asynchronous](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Asynchronous.html) annotation for sample if you use Java EE in your backend.

Then default transaction timeout in wildfly seems to be set to [300 seconds by default](http://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/8.2.0.Final/subsystem/transactions/index.html), not 600. Has someone already customized this setting by the past in you Wildfly configuration?

However, after all these remarks, if you really want to modify this timeout setting (don't do that! :) ), you could take a look at this thread: [How to change Transaction timeout in WildFly 8.2.0](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/260626)

Answer (score 0):

you have two timeouts. The browser timeout and server.
You can set the timeout on tomcat in $tomcat_home/conf/server.xml

**connectionTimeout="value"**

And browser, you can see [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/lorint/archive/2006/03/07/71625.aspx) how to set the timeout browser.

Comment: I am using apache as web server and widlfy as application server . Not using tomcat.